# MongoRepository findBetween without second argument

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to implement a simple date search via spring-data-mongodb/data-rest standard repositories. I have a class with a method:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {    
    List<Person> findByDateUpdatedBetween(@Param("fromDate") Date fromDate, @Param("toDate") Date toDate);
}
```

and here's how it works if no second argument provided:

```
{ "dateUpdated" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2016-02-13T05:41:38.000Z"} , "$lt" :  null }}
```

Is there a way to make it work without second argument? And is this a correct behavior anyway?

I was trying to mark it with a custom query like this:

```
@Query("{ 'dateUpdated' : { '$gt' : { '$date' : ?0} , '$lt' :  {'$cond' : { if: { ?1 : {'$ne' : null} }, then: '$currentDate', else: ?1 }} }}")
```

but no luck:

```
2016-02-14 21:45:47 [http-nio-8091-exec-1] TRACE o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(139) - Method [errorHtml] returned [ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {timestamp=Sun Feb 14 21:45:47 WITA 2016, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException, message=
{ 'dateUpdated' : { '$gt' : { '$date' : ?0} , '$lt' :  {'$cond' : { if: {  null  : {'$ne' : null} }, then: '$currentDate', else:  null  }} }}
                                        ^, path=/persons/search/findByDateUpdatedBetween}]
```

Comment: there's no optional parameters for derived queries in spring-data-mongodb. Finder methods are executed using `db.foo.find` but the `$cond` operator is for aggregations which require `db.foo.aggregate` - so despite the parsing error  I doubt the query will work. Still you can consider injecting a [custom implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Christoph. And yes, I ended up with custom implementation.